# Getting extremely low accuracy for my multiclass image classification network

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

I'm quite new to ML. I am trying to make a CNN to identify constellations from images using PyTorch Lightning. I've started with four constellations for now, with 20 images for each constellation. The following is my code:

My dataloader, along with transformations:

```
# dataLoader provider
class idDataLoader(pl.LightningDataModule):
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, data_dir, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.dataDir = data_dir
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
            transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=180),
            transforms.CenterCrop(224),
            transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0, contrast=2.0, saturation=0, hue=0),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
        ])

# Download Data
def prepare_data(self):
    # download
    ImageFolder(self.dataDir, transform=self.transform)

# Assign datasets based on stage.
def setup(self, stage=None):
    # Assign train/val datasets for use in dataloaders
    if stage == 'fit' or stage is None:
        id_dataset = ImageFolder(self.dataDir, transform=self.transform)
        self.id_train, self.id_val = random_split(id_dataset, [round(len(id_dataset) * 0.8), len(id_dataset) - round(len(id_dataset) * 0.8)])

    # Assign test dataset for use in dataloaders
    if stage == 'test' or stage is None:
        self.id_test = ImageFolder(self.dataDir, transform=self.transform)

# functions to return dataLoader modules.
def train_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.id_train, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)

def val_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.id_val, batch_size=self.batch_size)

def test_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.id_test, batch_size=self.batch_size)
```

My actual model:

```
# Model
class idModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, inputShape, numClasses, lr, batchSize):
        super().__init__()

        # define and save hpams
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.inputShape = inputShape
        self.numClasses = numClasses
        self.lr = lr
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.maxPool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

        self.validation_preds = []
        self.validation_targets = []

        # model architecture

        ## Layer 1 (input layer)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1)
        self.batchNorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)

        ## Layer 2
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.batchNorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)

        ## Layer 3
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, 1)
        self.batchNorm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)

        ## Layer 4
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, 1)
        self.batchNorm4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)

        ## Layer 5
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, 1)
        self.batchNorm5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)

        ## Layer 6 (reduces to 128 features)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(294912, 128)

        ## Layer 7 (output layer)
        numOfConstellations = 4
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, numOfConstellations)

        # activation functions
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

        # accuracy function
        self.accuracy = tm.Accuracy(task = "multiclass", num_classes = numOfConstellations)

    # forward prop
    def forward(self, x):
      # Layer 1 (input layer)
      x = self.conv1(x)
      x = self.batchNorm1(x)
      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.maxPool(x)

      # Layer 2
      x = self.conv2(x)
      x = self.batchNorm2(x)
      x = self.relu(x)

      # Layer 3
      x = self.conv3(x)
      x = self.batchNorm3(x)
      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.maxPool(x)

      # Layer 4
      x = self.conv4(x)
      x = self.batchNorm4(x)
      x = self.relu(x)

      # Layer 5
      x = self.conv5(x)
      x = self.batchNorm5(x)
      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.maxPool(x)

      # Layer 6
      x = pt.flatten(x, 1) # reduces tensor dimension to 1D
      x = self.fc1(x)
      x = self.relu(x)

      # Layer 7 (output layer)
      x = self.fc2(x)
      x = self.softmax(x) # returns probabilities for each constellation

      return x


    # Training step
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputImage, label = batch
        logits = self(inputImage) # get predictions
        loss = F.nll_loss(logits, label) # calculate loss using negative log

        prediction = pt.argmax(logits, dim=1) # get prediction with max probability
        accuracy = self.accuracy(prediction, label) # calculate accuracy

        # Log metrics
        self.log('trainingLoss', loss, on_step = True, on_epoch = True, logger = True)
        self.log('trainingAccuracy', accuracy, on_step = True, on_epoch = True, logger = True)

        return loss

    # Validation step
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # Same as training step except for logging method
        inputImage, label = batch
        logits = self(inputImage)
        loss = F.nll_loss(logits, label)

        prediction = pt.argmax(logits, dim=1)
        accuracy = self.accuracy(prediction, label)

        # Save the predictions and targets as instance attributes
        self.validation_preds.append(prediction)
        self.validation_targets.append(label)

        # Log metrics
        self.log('validationLoss', loss, prog_bar = True, logger = True)
        self.log('validationAccuracy', accuracy, prog_bar = True, logger = True)

        return loss

    # Test step
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # Same as training step except for logging method
        inputImage, label = batch
        logits = self(inputImage)
        loss = F.nll_loss(logits, label)

        prediction = pt.argmax(logits, dim=1)
        accuracy = self.accuracy(prediction, label)

        # Log metrics
        self.log('testLoss', loss, prog_bar = True, logger = True)
        self.log('testAccuracy', accuracy, prog_bar = True, logger = True)

        return loss

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
      # Get the predictions and targets from the validation step
      preds = pt.cat(self.validation_preds)
      targets = pt.cat(self.validation_targets)

      # Reset validation variables
      self.validation_preds = []
      self.validation_targets = []

      # Calculate the confusion matrix
      confmat = tm.functional.confusion_matrix(preds, targets, num_classes = self.numClasses, task = "multiclass")

      # Log the confusion matrix to TensorBoard
      self.logger.experiment.add_image('Confusion Matrix', plot_confusion_matrix(confmat))

      # Calculate and log a histogram to TensorBoard
      self.logger.experiment.add_histogram('Histogram', preds)

    # Configure optimisers
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimiser = pt.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr) # Adaptive Moment Estimation (Adam) optimiser
        scheduler = pt.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimiser, step_size=10, gamma=0.1)
        return [optimiser], [scheduler]
```

Training code:

```
# Training
tensorboard = pl_loggers.TensorBoardLogger(save_dir="")
trainer = pl.Trainer(logger = tensorboard)
model = idModel((1,224,224), 4, 1e-3, 5)
dataLoader = idDataLoader(dataDirPath, 5)

# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule=dataLoader)
    trainer.validate(model, datamodule=dataLoader)
    pt.save(model.state_dict(), 'checkpoint.ckpt')
```

With this, I am only getting a training and validation accuracy of about 22 per cent. How do I improve my accuracy?

Comment: The `F.nll_loss` accepts log-probabilities as input. You may need to add `F.log_softmax`, for instance: `F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(input, dim=1), target)`